# Apex Scheduled Jobs Error

Tags: apex, batch, scheduled-apex, schedulebatch, platform-bug

I am trying to scheduled a job but I get the following error: `You have exceeded the maximum number (100) of Apex scheduled jobs.`

However when I checked my current scheduled jobs, I see only 2 jobs which have a next scheduled run as seen in the screenshot below. The rest of the jobs ran once and do not have a next scheduled run. In CronTrigger, their status is Deleted. The total count of such jobs is 2600~. And these are jobs cumulative since 2011. But we started getting this error from the last 7-8 days.

Am I missing something here?

[image: Scheduled Job Description]

Comment: Just wondering.. you've  'Next Page' link available in the screenshot . Are you sure.. you don't have active  Scheduled jobs in other pages ?

Comment: Yes, I checked that. In the screenshot above, I have sorted it descending based on next scheduled run. Also did a query on CronTrigger where NextRunTime != null. It returned the same number - 2.

Comment: From where you are scheduling the jobs? Any Apex class?

Comment: Yes, Apex Class.